# How can I split my Login process into functions?

Tags: php, function, authentication, module, session-variables

I'm currently using a modified version of a login script I found online.
Can anybody suggest some ways of modularizing the code into functions?

Here is the code for the login page:

```
<?php
include("db.php");
include("login_fns.php");
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
// username and password sent from Form
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 
$password=md5($password);
$sql="SELECT * FROM client_login WHERE Username='$username' and Password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$client_ref = $row['Client_ref'];
$user_level = $row['user_level'];
// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1)
{

$_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
$_SESSION['client_ref'] = $client_ref;
$_SESSION['user'] = $username;

if ($user_level == '1') {
header('Location: admin.php');
} else {

header('Location: myaccount.php');
}
}
else 
{
echo "Error logging in!";
}
}
?>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<label>UserName :</label>
<input type="text" name="username"/><br />
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value=" Login "/><br />
</form>
```

Ideally, I'd like a function for the user account search and the session setting. I previously tried to copy snippets of this code into a separate php functions file, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Please don't use `md5()` for password hashing. You might as well save it in plain text.

Comment: I know. I'm going to change it to SHA1 and then salt it. I though it was best to keep it simple for the sake of the exercise. :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this? :)

## The function

```
<?php
function checkLogin($username, $password) {
    global $bd;

    $returnArray=array();
    $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($bd, $username);
    $password=md5($password);
    
    $getUser=mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT `Client_ref`,`user_level` FROM client_login WHERE Username='$username' and Password='$password'");
    $arrayUser=mysqli_fetch_array($getUser);
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($getUser) == 0)
    {
        $returnArray['error']='true';
        $returnArray['errormsg']='User not found in the database.';
        
        return $returnArray;
    }
    
    $returnArray['Client_ref']=$row['Client_ref'];
    $returnArray['user_level']=$row['user_level'];
    
    return $returnArray;
}
?>
```

## Rest of the code

```
<?php
include("db.php");
include("login_fns.php");
session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $username=$_POST['username']; 
    $password=$_POST['password']; 
    
    $loginArray=checkLogin($username, $password);

    if(!isset($loginArray['error']))
    {
        $_SESSION['user_level'] = $loginArray['Client_ref'];
        $_SESSION['client_ref'] = $loginArray['user_level'];
        $_SESSION['user'] = $username;

        if($loginArray['user_level'] == '1')
        {
            header('Location: admin.php');
        }
        else
        {
            header('Location: myaccount.php');
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Error logging in!";
        echo "The detailed error message is: ".$returnArray['errormsg'];
    }
}
?>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <label>UserName :</label>
    <input type="text" name="username"/><br />
    
    <label>Password :</label>
    <input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
    
    <input type="submit" value=" Login "/><br />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, it seems to just stay on the login page. There's no response.

Comment: Please enable PHP error reporting on your server. Probably, you're getting the error message "Headers already sent.... output started at ..... at line XX".

Comment: PHP error reporting is enabled. Perhaps it's to do with the database connection.

Comment: Okay. Do you have any open mysql_connect() connection? (db.php i guess) Can you post db.php and hide the database password?

Comment: Yes. login.php has an included mysql_connect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21411/discussion-between-robinjoeh-and-edward)

Comment: Hmm, it's doing what it was before; not responding.

Comment: Please message in the chat Edward.